# Сборка и подключение библиотеки DCMTK Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

Есть библиотека для работы с файлами DICOM(специфические медицинские изображения) - https://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en Для VS или из под Linux-a все спококойно собирается и подключается. Не получается ее собрать и подключить в Qt Creator (компилятор MinGW) в Windows, постоянно ошибки при cmake. Если кто-то сталкивался или готов помочь, отзовитесь пожалуйста

Comment: Собирал её с помощью cmake, правда на Linux. Возможно, [этот конфиг](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=dcmtk) поможет (смотрите раздел build)